# Adding Custom Attributes to ASMX Web Service Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, attributes, httphandler

I have some web methods in an asmx web service that currently look like this:

```
[WebMethod(false, System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionOption.NotSupported)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XElement GetSomeData(int dataId)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
[WebMethod(false, System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionOption.NotSupported)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
[EnableSomeCustomSecurityCheck(true)]
public XElement GetSomeData(int dataId)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Where "EnableSomeCustomSecurityCheck" tells it that there should be an additional token parameter that needs to be validated. I basically want to avoid copying this code to every method that needs it:

```
[WebMethod(false, System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionOption.NotSupported)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XElement GetSomeData(int dataId, string securityToken)
{
    SomeClass.CheckSecurityToken(securityToken);

    // Do something.
}
```

I'm a bit lost as to where to begin. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how I can add this functionality without losing any features the asmx handling already has?

Comment: What's the difference between adding one line of code to every method versus adding one line of attribute to every method? What's the benefit you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You'd have an easier time of this using WCF.

Comment: @pmartin: Because I don't believe it describes how the method itself needs to work, but rather how the framework should react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the attribute on the method, and then have a [Soap Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) check the attribute and behave accordingly.